# Backbone Model Scope Issue with Backbone Validation Custom Function

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a scope issue in my Backbone model. I am trying to refer to a models function inside the Backbone.Validation object.

Ie, I cant access the model function `validateDob` from within the `validation` object/map:

```
Backbone.Model.extend({

    validation: {
        firstname: { required: true, msg: _('First Name is required').translate() }
    ,   dobday: this.validateDob    // this. refers to the immediate object {}
    ,   dobmonth: validateDob       // undefined function
    ,   dobyear: this.validateDob   // How can I access the function validateDob?
    }

,   validateDob: function(value)  {
        var selDay = $('select[name="dobday"] option:selected').val();
        var selMonth = $('select[name="dobmonth"] option:selected').val();
        var selYear = $('select[name="dobyear"] option:selected').val();

        if (!Utils.isAdult(selDay, selMonth, selYear))
            return _('You have to be at least 18 years old.').translate();
    }
});
```

Any advice how I can set this up?

Comment: How you call this method ?  try  like example `dobday: this.validateDob()`

Comment: Which validation plugin are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code, `validateDob` doesn't require access to the instance, hence you can just make it a named function as follows:

```js
function validateDob(value) {
  var selDay = $('select[name="dobday"] option:selected').val();
  var selMonth = $('select[name="dobmonth"] option:selected').val();
  var selYear = $('select[name="dobyear"] option:selected').val();

  if (!Utils.isAdult(selDay, selMonth, selYear))
    return _('You have to be at least 18 years old.').translate();
}

Backbone.Model.extend({
  validation: {
    firstname: {
      required: true,
      msg: _('First Name is required').translate()
    },
    dobday: validateDob,
    dobmonth: validateDob,
    dobyear: validateDob
  },
  validateDob: validateDob
});
```

---

But, accessing values directly from DOM using global selectors is not a recommended practice. You should be setting these values to modal attributes using selectors scoped to view element.

In that case, assuming you're using [backbone.validation](https://github.com/thedersen/backbone.validation) plugin, you can define a function that returns the validation config like:

```js
Backbone.Model.extend({
  validation: function() {
    return {
      firstname: {
        required: true,
        msg: _('First Name is required').translate()
      },
      dobday: this.validateDob, // this should be modal instance now
      dobmonth: this.validateDob,
      dobyear: this.validateDob
    }
  },
  validateDob: function(value) {
    // Now context should be the modal instance so you can do this.get('prop')
    var selDay = $('select[name="dobday"] option:selected').val();
    var selMonth = $('select[name="dobmonth"] option:selected').val();
    var selYear = $('select[name="dobyear"] option:selected').val();

    if (!Utils.isAdult(selDay, selMonth, selYear))
      return _('You have to be at least 18 years old.').translate();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
 Backbone.Model.extend({
    validation: {
        firstname: { required: true, msg: _('First Name is required').translate() }
    },
    initialize:function() {
        this.validation.dobyear= this.validateDob;
        //you can other props similarly
    },
    validateDob: function(value)  {
        var selDay = $('select[name="dobday"] option:selected').val();
        var selMonth = $('select[name="dobmonth"] option:selected').val();
        var selYear = $('select[name="dobyear"] option:selected').val();

        if (!Utils.isAdult(selDay, selMonth, selYear))
            return _('You have to be at least 18 years old.').translate();
    }
});
```